# notification launched at boot

Tags: android

Because Alarms are deleted turning off the device I need to reset them at boot. I'm doing that in a service at BOOT_COMPLETED, and it works. The issue cames when the time to fire the alarm is achieved and the alarm is directly launched. This alarm has to add a notification and I can see this notification on my emulator, but just for a few seconds, because is automatically deleted by the system. Do you know the reason for that? Is it something related with the boot process? I have to shut down my emulator closing the emulator window because the turn off button takes ages.

Comment: I have it!!! I read that _"Stopping an application is there for the user to stop  everything associated with it -- processes, alarms, services, notifications, etc."_ And every time I relaunch an app it seems it is completly reinstalled, this reinstallation causes the app stops and the notification deleted. If I just start the emulator using the AVD Manager it works fine.